# Oauth multipart request

Tags: java, android, oauth, multipart

I want send some files to server with Oauth authorization.
Does anybody know how create Oauth multipart request?
I use [Oauth](https://code.google.com/p/oauth/) lib for another requests. How can I add to the lib ability to send multipart?
I have a plan to rewrite [HttpClient4.java](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/core/httpclient4/src/main/java/net/oauth/client/httpclient4/HttpClient4.java) class.
Does anybody had such experience?